# Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)-- MYSQL Command line connectivity

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run MYSQL Server from command line and I am getting the above error on executing `mysql -u root -p command`. I tried to rectify the issue following the below mentioned logs but the same error comes again.

LOG DATA:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqld -nt --standalone --console
```

```
150615  0:30:10 [Warning] option 'new': boolean value 't' wasn't recognized. Set
 to OFF.
150615  0:30:10 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44) starting as process 3768 ...
150615  0:30:10 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 675.0M
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\MySQL Da
tafiles\ibdata1
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back

150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB c
reated
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files fu
ll of
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be caref
ul: do not
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
150615  0:30:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150615  0:30:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

150615  0:30:10 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: INNODB
150615  0:30:10 [ERROR] Aborting

150615  0:30:10 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
150615  0:30:10 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
```

Run `mysqld` as admin user. You can use windows command `runas` to run from console as admin.

Comment: I tried to run mysqld service from /bin as admin user, the same error is coming again while connecting to the server. Is this a bug in MySQL version 5.6? I am not sure.